# License Agreement for XNA program

Tags: c#-4.0, licensing, xna-4.0

I was just wondering what license agreement I should include in an XNA Framework game set-up file. Currently, I'm using GNU license, but I'm not sure if this is appropriate or not...

I just want to make sure that I am using the correct agreement, or if it is suitable enough to cover this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this question belong here...

Anyways, my understand matches [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA#XNA_Framework):

> XNA framework games that target the Xbox platform can currently only be distributed by members of the Microsoft XNA Creator's Club which carries a $99/year subscription fee.[4] Desktop applications can be distributed free of charge under Microsoft's current licensing.

and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA#License_agreement):

> The Microsoft XNA Framework 2.0 EULA specifically prohibits the distribution of commercial networked games that connect to Xbox Live and/or Games for Windows Live in the absence of a specific agreement signed by both the developer and Microsoft.[19] This means that XNA Game Studio can still be used to develop commercial games and other programs for the Windows platform, although Microsoft's networking support code for Xbox/Windows Live cannot be used. Self-developed network code can still be used inside the developer's XNA project.

So as far as releasing it as long as Microsoft is fine with it, I figure it's fine.

[link](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#NonFreeTools)
(for GNU Licenses)

> Which programs you used to edit the source code, or to compile it, or study it, or record it, usually makes no difference for issues concerning the licensing of that source code.